# Creating "components" with Meteor and Handlebars

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, handlebars.js

I'm exploring the Meteor-framework. I've a lot of experience with Java EE / JavaServer Faces (JSF), but I'm new to JavaScript-development. I'm trying to create a nicely formatted "horizontal form", as described at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms. My problem is, that this gives me a lot of repeated HTML for each input field, which is not DRY...

So, I'm trying to create a construct like "composite components" in JSF 2.x. This means I'm looking for a way to call a Meteor-template and substitute some values in it.

My template is like this:

```
<template name="formField">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="{{this.id}}">{{this.label}}:</label>
    <div class="controls">
      {{this.formField}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I was able to get it partially working, by calling it like this:

```
{{> formField labels.x}}
```

Where I defined the `labels` map like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.labels = {
  "x": {id: 'idx', label: 'labelx'},
  "y": {id: 'idy', label: 'labely'},
  "z": {id: 'idz', label: 'labelz'}
}
```

The problem is, of course, substituting the `<input>`-element in the template. I tried all sorts of ways to do this, but there are several problems:

- I could add the `<input>`-element to my `formField`-template, but then I cannot bind the `value` of that `<input>`-element to a property of the JavaScript-object that is being edited in the form.
- I could create a function that returns an `<input>`-element, but then I would end up with markup-code in my JavaScript-sources.

Another problem is that I'm not really satisfied with the `Template.myTemplate.labels`-map. It seems this is unavoidable, since I was not able to use any literal values. It would be nice if I was able to call the template like this:

```
{{> formField idx labelx}}
{{> formField idy labely}}
{{> formField idz labelz}}
```

To conclude, I have basically one question: what's the best way to create some sort of component with Meteor/Handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

Forms are on the roadmap:

https://trello.com/card/easy-forms/508721606e02bb9d570016ae/8

But in particular check out this discussion:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1054 (from the above link).

As for creating components in Meteor, there is no *the* way to do it, but you might want to check out how the accounts packages work, as that's pretty isolated, extensible, and a form:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the roadmap. While a specific form-package sounds great, I'm currently just looking for a way to create a reusable component. I had a look at the accounts packages, but that was a rather confusing experience. I did not found any HTML and a lot of JavaScript-code that is specific for the login-process. So I don't think that's a good example for creating reusable components.